# Find all values that do not fit within any of multiple defined ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table with a list of start and end dates along with another table that contains a range of dates. I want to find out which of the dates in the latter table do not fit between a range of dates in the former. Given this example:

***Valid date ranges***

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| SensorID | StartDate  | EndDate    |
+----------+------------+------------+
|        1 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-08 |
|        1 | 2018-01-10 | 2018-01-13 |
|        1 | 2018-01-14 | 2018-01-17 |
|        1 | 2018-01-21 | 2018-01-31 |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

***List of given dates***

```
+----------+------------+-------+
| SensorID | Read_Date  | Value |
+----------+------------+-------+
|        1 | 2018-01-01 |   100 |
|        1 | 2018-01-02 |   200 |
|        1 | 2018-01-03 |   300 |
|        1 | 2018-01-09 |   400 |
|        1 | 2018-01-10 |   400 |
|        1 | 2018-01-14 |   250 |
|        1 | 2018-01-18 |   300 |
|        1 | 2018-01-18 |   400 |
|        1 | 2018-01-19 |   350 |
|        1 | 2018-01-24 |   400 |
+----------+------------+-------+
```

The end result should be the full record from the second table, i.e.

```
+----------+------------+-------+
| SensorID | Read_Date  | Value |
+----------+------------+-------+
|        1 | 2018-01-09 |   400 |
|        1 | 2018-01-18 |   300 |
|        1 | 2018-01-18 |   400 |
|        1 | 2018-01-19 |   350 |
+----------+------------+-------+
```

I thought about finding all records that are valid records using `BETWEEN` then `EXCEPT` those from those from the full dataset, but it's too large. Is there a way to join using `NOT BETWEEN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is as simple as:

```
SELECT *
FROM given_dates
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM valid_date_ranges
    WHERE given_dates.SensorID = valid_date_ranges.SensorID
    AND   given_dates.Read_Date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
)
```

It is also possible to write the above as `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE keycol IS NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, [found this answer that uses similar logic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139980/select-rows-for-which-at-least-one-row-per-set-meets-a-condition)

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're taking is valid, but could be made more efficient.  I typically avoid using a distinct clause my statements unless absolutely necessary.  They often are signs that the join is written incorrectly and/or non-optimally.

I recommend using a left anti-semi join to more efficiently return your data.  The following article helps explain a bit further what I'd suggest you do: https://sqlity.net/en/1360/a-join-a-day-the-left-anti-semi-join/

I would recommend something like this which would likely have performance:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #record_dates AS rd
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT  TOP (1)
                vd.SensorID
        FROM    #valid_dates AS vd
        WHERE   vd.SensorID = rd.SensorID
            AND rd.Read_Date BETWEEN vd.StartDate AND vd.EndDate
        ORDER BY vd.SensorID ASC
    )
```

I should note that I'm assuming that SensorID is indexed.  I have found that adding an ORDER BY on the clustered index when selecting a top(1) record assists with the query plan although you might experience better performance by disregarding that piece.